# How to dynamically load models inside an installable hook in Sails.js

Tags: sails.js

We are thinking of making one of our applications very modular, creating hooks for the different sections.
What would be needed to do for "injecting" a hook/models folder with its own models into the sails instance?
I tried to find if there is a sails-hook-utils or something like that that allows for late model/controller/service injection, on hooks, but found none. I'm about to create a module for it, https://github.com/luislobo/sails-hook-utils, but it would be great if anyone has some head starts on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, right after digging more, I just found a module that does exactly what I need. I didn't test it yet, but will do it now.
https://github.com/leeroybrun/sails-util-mvcsloader